# xp_cmdshell in a transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, transaction, scripting

I need to run multiple scripts in a certain folder in a transaction and rollback if there are any errors. At this point I'm just trying to get the rollback to work without a try catch.

Currently when I run the script, it gets the proper list of sql files recursively, but does not rollback the changes if there is an error. If there are 10 files and 3 complete but there is an error on the 4th, the first 3 files do not rollback.

Here is my script:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE ##SQLFiles ( SQLFileName VARCHAR(2000))
GO

DECLARE @folderPath VARCHAR(100) = 'folder\path' 
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(8000) = 'dir /b /s "' + @folderPath + '\*.sql"'

INSERT INTO ##SQLFiles
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_cmdshell @cmd
GO 

DECLARE cFiles CURSOR LOCAL FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT
        [SQLFileName]
    FROM ##SQLFiles
    WHERE [SQLFileName] IS NOT NULL AND
          [SQLFileName] != 'NULL'
    ORDER BY [SQLFileName]

DECLARE @folderPath         VARCHAR(100) = 'folder\path' 
DECLARE @vFileName          VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @vSQLStmt           VARCHAR(4000)

SELECT * FROM ##SQLFiles

OPEN cFiles
FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @vFileName
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    SET @vSQLStmt = 'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''osql -S ServerName -U UserName -P "password" -d dbname -i "' + @folderPath + @vFileName + '"'''
    PRINT @vSQLStmt
    EXECUTE (@vSQLStmt)

    FETCH NEXT FROM cFiles INTO @vFileName
END

CLOSE cFiles
DEALLOCATE cFiles
GO

DROP TABLE ##SQLFiles
GO

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

Is there any way to get the changes made by the files to be rolled back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, absolutely impossible. Each sqlcmd invocation is a different *session* and transaction cannot span sessions.

Your use of a transaction on the script that invokes the sqlcmd is completely useless, it has *nothing* to do with the scripts being run.

Comment: Even if the `xp_cmdshell` invocation *was* part of the same "session", the commands processed by the shell cannot be "rolled back" since the OS itself has no concept of transactions.  The only way to "roll back" those commands would be to perform an equal-but-opposite action via `xp_cmdshell` upon failure of the T-SQL action(s).